# I made a `box' float environment, and now I would like to put the caption inside the box

Tags: floats, captions, environments

I made a box float using the following:

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Box}{t}{bx}[chapter]
```

and

```
\begin{Box}[htp]
  \label{box:test}
  \fcolorbox{black}{boxgray}{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{The text goes here}}
\end{Box}
```

I would like to have the label, i.e. 'Box 1' appear inside the box in the first row of text. Does anyone have an idea of how to implement this?

A basic version of the file I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}


\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{215,215,215}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Box}{t}{bx}[section]


\begin{document}


\section{example}

Something about \ref{box:test}.

\begin{Box}[htp]
  \label{box:test}
  \fcolorbox{black}{boxgray}{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{The text goes here}}
\end{Box}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You need an anchor for the label. This is normally done by `caption` and not by the float environment. This is the reason why you should put the label after `caption`. In your case there is no anchor. A trick would be:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{Box}{\refstepcounter{Box}}
```

However there is no hint inside your environment that the reference number contains to the environment. So I suggest the following:

1. Define the new float environment with `newfloat`
2. Related to point 1 you can setup the caption with `captionsetup`. (I know `caption` supports `float`)
3. Using `tcolorbox` to draw the frame around the caption.

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{215,215,215}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}%loaded by caption too
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[%
fileext=bx,%
within=section,%
placement=t,
name=Box,%
listname={List of Boxes},%
]{Boxed}
\captionsetup[Boxed]{justification=justified,format=plain,singlelinecheck=false,skip=0pt}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand*\boxedcaption[2][box:\arabic{Boxed}]%
{\begin{tcolorbox}\caption{#2}\label{#1}\end{tcolorbox}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}


\section{example}

Something about \ref{box:test}.

\begin{Boxed}[htp]
\lipsum[1]
\boxedcaption[box:test]{Text goes here}
\end{Boxed}

Something about \ref{box:2}.

\begin{Boxed}[htp]
\lipsum[2]
\boxedcaption{Text goes here}
\end{Boxed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or do you want a frame around the environment Box?